# Route all traffic throuch a Linux machine

Tags: linux, router, iptables, voip

I want do route all traffic from and to two IP phones (SNOM D305) through a Linux machine for debugging purposes. The IP phones have a builtin 2-port switch each and the setup looks like this:

[Production setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4b6sK.jpg)

To be able to see the traffic I altered the setup like this:

[Debugging setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vm98A.jpg)

I gave the only NIC in the Linux machine two IPs

```
ifconfig eth0 10.0.0.3 up
ifconfig eth0:1 10.0.1.100
```

I enabled IP forwarding

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

and configured its IP as gateway for the two IP phones. Then I configured NAT like this:

```
iptables -t NAT -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

With this the phones are able to register to the SIP server. It is also possible to make calls from the phones but all I see is traffic going from the phones to outside and I can not hear any sound in both directions. What do I have to add to this to make it work?

Comment: Yoour phones are probably the same subnet. That means that no routing occurs. Can you show us what are the masks?

Comment: It will be very difficult to get the debugging setup to work reliably (even if you set the Linux host as gateway, you'll have to disable ICMP redirect somehow). It's much simpler if the Linux host has two ethernet interfaces (or if you can simulate two, e.g. by using a VLAN to the PBX host).

Comment: @MichaelManuelVandycke: NetMasks where 255.255.255.0
I think dirkt was on the right track with what he wrote on ICMP redirection. I managed to get a machine with two NICs and setup a bridge. Seems to solve my problem.